# How to get updated list values from JSP in my action?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, annotations, type-conversion

I have a JSP in which I am iterating over a list and creating an editable table.

```
<s:iterator value="test" id="countryList">
  <tr>
    <td><s:textfield name="countryCode" value="%{countryCode}" theme="simple" /></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="countryName" value="%{countryName}" theme="simple" /></td>
  </tr>
 </s:iterator>
```

**My list:**

```
List<Country> test = new ArrayList<Country>();
```

**Country class:**

```
public class Country {
    private String countryCode;
    private String countryName;


and the getter setters......
```

**and say I populate the list like:**

```
Country country = new Country();
Country country1 = new Country();

country.setCountryCode("1");
country.setCountryName("India");

country1.setCountryCode("2");
country1.setCountryName("US");

test.add(country);
test.add(country1);
```

Now when I change the values of `countrycode` and `countryname` in the JSP, I should get the updated values in my action. But am I not able to. Is there any way to get these updated values.

Comment: does struts use %{variableName} ?

Comment: yes...it supports OGNL expressions

Comment: so shouldn't it be ${variableName}

Comment: It should be....but %{variableName} also works..i get the values in the jsp..but when i update the values and submit the form, i dont get the updated values in the action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `Country` object is created when the `params` interceptor is populating your list using indexed property access.

```
<s:iterator value="test" id="countryList" status="stat">
  <tr>
    <td><s:textfield name="countryList[%{#stat.index}].countryCode" value="%{countryCode}" theme="simple" /></td>
    <td><s:textfield name="countryList[%{#stat.index}].countryName" value="%{countryName}" theme="simple" /></td>
  </tr>
 </s:iterator>
```

To let the struts populate the list you should use a type conversion annotation or equivalent in the xml configuration.

```
@Element(value = Country.class)
@Key(value = String.class)
@KeyProperty(value = "countryCode") 
@CreateIfNull(value = true)
private List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>;
```

Comment: It works!!!Thanks Romans...thanks a lot...saved my day. Was a nice thing to learn

Comment: Great, now you have to code to compare lists and update values. But you didn't save the previuos list, you need to fetch it again if you don't mind to hardcode values in the action. Better put it in the session because actions are recreated each time you make a request.