# How to post an array of custom objects with missing entries to Struts2 action

Tags: java, html, struts2, type-conversion, xwork

[Tabular Inputs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=13904#content/view/13904) This suggests to use `XWorkList` instead of `ArrayList`, when the size of array is unknown & there are gaps in between.

But `XWorkList` is not generic & it has no empty constructor, according to [documentation](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/conversion/impl/XWorkList.html).

My question is how to use `XWorkList` or is there any way to submit list of beans with some items missing in the list ?

**Sample Html:**

```xml
<input name="lst[0].name"/>
<input name="lst[3].name"/>
<input name="lst[4].name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `List` contract is an ordered collection. It can't have missing indeces. About `XWorkList` it's just an other implementation of the list, capable of creating new elements for the specified index by filling gap for required elements. What is said for `add(int, Object)`

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
> Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
> subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
> This method is guaranteed to work since it will create empty beans to
> fill the gap between the current list size and the requested index to
> enable the element to be set.

Another approach for creating new beans in the list is to use [type conversion](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html). Or using annotations like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19155411/573032) answer.

Comment: well in that case, ArrayList also does the same, it creates null for missing entries. Is there any way, I can prevent these null-entries from being created or remove them ?

Comment: No, if you specify index greater than size of `ArrayList` it will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

It's extending `ArrayList` and has a constructor that takes a `Class`. Thus you would change:

```
List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
foo.add("bar");
foo.add("");
foo.add("");
foo.add("foobar");
foo.add("barfoo");
```

into:

```
List<String> foo = new XWorkList(String.class);
foo.add("bar");
foo.add(3, "foobar");
foo.add(4, "barfoo");
```