# HTML tags listing does not binds value in the action Arraylist

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, arraylist, struts2

I have a dynamic add/delete row functionality in the struts2 application.

Now the first value is properly bound from JSP to action since the first value exists with struts tags (`s:select`) in the JSP, but the dynamic rows added from the Javascript are not getting bind to the Action list. The action `ArrayList` values are not bound, this is the code I have so far:

```
<legend class="legendtitle">Training Needs Analysis</legend>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="trainingTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="Htd_one1">
                <div align="center">Course:</div>
            </td>
            <td class="Htd_one1">
                <div align="center">Course Name (if Others):<span class="mandatory">*</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="Htd_one1">
                <div align="center">Training Type:<span class="mandatory">*</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="Htd_one1">
                <div align="center">Reason For Recommendation:<span class="mandatory">*</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="Htd_one1">
                <div align="center">Action</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="dataone1" width="20%">
                <s:div align="center">
                    <s:select list="courseNameList" name="appTrngMstrList[0].courseCode" headerKey="0" headerValue="SELECT" id="courseCode0"
                        onchange="enableDetailCourseSection(this.value,0)" theme="simple" listKey="displayKey" cssClass="txtbox"
                        listValue="displayValue" />
                </s:div>
            </td>
            <s:hidden name="hrAppHeader.appHidenVarTrngMstrList[0].courseCode" id="courseCodeHide0"></s:hidden>

            <td class="dataone1">
                <s:div id="courseOthersTextTd" align="center">
                    <s:textfield id="courseOthers0" name="appTrngMstrList[0].courseOthers" cssClass="txtbox_mandatory" theme="simple" cols="50"
                        rows="3" maxLength="200" onblur="convertToUpper(this)" />
                </s:div>
            </td>
            <s:hidden name="hrAppHeader.appHidenVarTrngMstrList[0].courseOthers" id="courseOthersHide0"></s:hidden>
            <td class="dataone1">
                <s:div id="trainingTypeTextTd" align="center">
                    <s:select headerKey="0" headerValue="SELECT" list="#{'I':'INTERNAL','E':'EXTERNAL'}" name="appTrngMstrList[0].trainingType"
                        id="trainingType0" theme="simple" cssClass="txtbox_mandatory"></s:select>
                </s:div>
            </td>
            <s:hidden name="hrAppHeader.appHidenVarTrngMstrList[0].trainingType" id="trainingTypeHide0"></s:hidden>
            <td class="dataone2">
                <s:div align="center">
                    <s:textarea name="appTrngMstrList[0].reasonOfRecomndtn" id="reasonOfRecomndtn0" cols="40" theme="simple" cssClass="txtbox_mandatory_big"
                        onblur="convertToUpper(this);" onkeydown="textCounter(this,4000);" onkeyup="textCounter(this,4000);"
                    />
                </s:div>
                <s:hidden name="hrAppHeader.appHidenVarTrngMstrList[0].reasonOfRecomndtn" id="reasonOfRecomndtnHide0"></s:hidden>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn" id="deletSelfrowid" onclick="deleteTrainingRow(0);" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table id="table1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
            <input type="button" class="btn" value="Add Row" id="addSelfrowId" onclick="addTrainingRow(0)">&nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function addTrainingRow(index) {
    var str = "";
    var rowCnt = document.getElementById('rowCnt').value;
    var tbody =
        document.getElementById("trainingTable").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];

    var row = document.createElement("TR");

    var check = rowCnt % 2;
    if (check == 0) {
        row.className = "oddrow";
    }
    else {
        row.className = "evenrow";
    }

    var optionValue1 = new Array();

    var keyValue1 = new Array();

    var courseCode = document.getElementById('courseCode' + index);

    var length1 = courseCode.options.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
        dropdownKey = courseCode.options[i].value;
        keyValue1[i] = dropdownKey;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
        dropdownValues = courseCode.options[i].text;
        optionValue1[i] = dropdownValues;
    }


    var optionValue2 = new Array();

    var keyValue2 = new Array();
    var strVal = "";
    strVal = strVal + '<option value=\"0">SELECT</option><option value=\"I\">INTERNAL</option><option value=\"E\">EXTERNAL</option>';
    var s1 = "";
    var s2 = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < optionValue1.length; i++) {
        s1 = s1 + '<option value="' + keyValue1[i] + '">' + optionValue1[i] + '</option>';
    }
    s2 = s2 + '<option value="0">SELECT</option>';

    //var str1='<div align=\"center\"><select class=\"txtbox\" theme=\"simple\" id=\"courseCode'+rowCnt+'\" name=\"appTrngMstrList['+rowCnt+'].courseCode\" onchange=\"enableDetailCourseSection(this.value,'+rowCnt+');\">'+s1+'</select></div>';
    var str1 = '<div align=\"center\"><select class=\"txtbox\" theme=\"simple\" id=\"courseCode' + rowCnt + '\" name=\"appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].courseCode\" onchange=\"enableDetailCourseSection(this.value,' + rowCnt + ');\">' + s1 + '</select></div><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hrAppHeader.appHidenVarTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].courseCode\" id=\"courseCodeHide' + rowCnt + '\"/>';
    var str4 = '<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].courseOthers\" id=\"courseOthers' + rowCnt + '\" class=\"txtbox_mandatory\"   theme=\"simple\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"3\" maxLength=\"200\" onblur=\"convertToUpper(this)\"/></div><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hrAppHeader.appHidenVarTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].courseOthers\" id=\"courseOthersHide' + rowCnt + '\"/>';

    var str2 = '<div id=\"trainingTypeTextTd' + rowCnt + '\" align=\"center\"><select class=\"txtbox_mandatory\" theme=\"simple\"  id=\"trainingType' + rowCnt + '\" name=\"appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].trainingType\">' + strVal + '</select></div><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hrAppHeader.appHidenVarTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].trainingType\" id=\"trainingTypeHide' + rowCnt + '\"/>';

    var str5 = '<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" theme=\"simple\" class=\"txtbox_mandatory_big\" cols=\"40\"  name=\"appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].reasonOfRecomndtn\" id=\"reasonOfRecomndtn' + rowCnt + '\"    onblur=\"convertToUpper(this);\" onkeydown=\"textCounter(this,4000);\" onkeyup=\"textCounter(this,4000);\"/></div><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hrAppHeader.appHidenVarTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].reasonOfRecomndtn\" id=\"reasonOfRecomndtnHide' + rowCnt + '\"/>';

    var str8 = '<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"btn\" id=\"deletSelfrowid\" onclick=\"deleteTrainingRow(' + rowCnt + ');\"/></div>';


    var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
    td1.innerHTML = str1;
    var td4 = document.createElement("TD");
    td4.innerHTML = str4;

    var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
    td2.innerHTML = str2;

    var td5 = document.createElement("TD");
    td5.innerHTML = str5;

    var td8 = document.createElement("TD");
    td8.innerHTML = str8;

    td1.className = "td_one1";
    td4.className = "td_one1";
    td2.className = "td_one1";
    td5.className = "td_one1";
    td8.className = "td_one1";

    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td4);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td5);
    row.appendChild(td8);


    tbody.appendChild(row);


    //set the number of rows
    document.getElementById("rowCnt").value = Number(rowCnt) + 1;
}




function deleteTrainingRow(id) {
    var optionValue1 = new Array();
    var optionValue2 = new Array();

    var keyValue1 = new Array();
    var keyValue2 = new Array();
    //Get the existing number of rows

    var existingNumOfRows = document.getElementById("rowCnt").value;

    var atLeastOneRowSelected = false;
    // TO check atleast one row is not deleted.
    var count = 0;

    if (parseInt(existingNumOfRows) == 1) {
        alert("Cannot delete all rows.");
        return false;
    }

    var index = 1;
    var rowCnt = 0;
    var recommendStr = '';
    var otherStr = '';
    var tempArray = new Array();//This will be used to take the backup of the current unselected rows

    for (var i = 0; i < existingNumOfRows; i++) {
        if (parseInt(id) != parseInt(i)) {
            var row = document.createElement("TR");


            var check = rowCnt % 2;
            if (check == 0) {
                row.className = "oddrow";
            }
            else {
                row.className = "evenrow";
            }

            var courseCode = document.getElementById('courseCode' + i);

            var length1 = courseCode.options.length;
            for (var j = 0; j < length1; j++) {
                dropdownKey = courseCode.options[j].value;
                keyValue1[j] = dropdownKey;
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < length1; j++) {
                dropdownValues = courseCode.options[j].text;
                optionValue1[j] = dropdownValues;
            }

            var s1 = "";

            for (var j = 0; j < optionValue1.length; j++) {
                if (document.getElementById("courseCode" + i).selectedIndex == j) {
                    s1 = s1 + '<option value="' + keyValue1[j] + '" selected>' + optionValue1[j] + '</option>';
                }
                else {
                    s1 = s1 + '<option value="' + keyValue1[j] + '">' + optionValue1[j] + '</option>';
                }
            }

            var trainingType = document.getElementById('trainingType' + i);
            var length2 = trainingType.options.length;
            for (var j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
                dropdownKey = trainingType.options[j].value;
                keyValue2[j] = dropdownKey;
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
                dropdownValues = trainingType.options[j].text;
                optionValue2[j] = dropdownValues;
            }
            var s2 = "";

            for (var j = 0; j < optionValue2.length; j++) {
                if (document.getElementById("trainingType" + i).selectedIndex == j) {
                    s2 = s2 + '<option value="' + keyValue2[j] + '" selected>' + optionValue2[j] + '</option>';
                }
                else {
                    s2 = s2 + '<option value="' + keyValue2[j] + '">' + optionValue2[j] + '</option>';
                }
            }


            recommendStr = document.getElementById('reasonOfRecomndtn' + i).value;

            //alert(document.getElementById("courseCode"+i).selectedIndex);
            if (document.getElementById("courseCode" + i).selectedIndex == "20") {
                otherStr = document.getElementById('courseOthers' + i).value;
            }

            var str1 = '<div align=\"center\"><select class=\"txtbox\" theme=\"simple\" id=\"courseCode' + rowCnt + '\" name="\appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].courseCode\" onchange=\"enableDetailCourseSection(this.value,' + rowCnt + ');\">' + s1 + '</select></div>';
            var str4 = '<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].courseOthers\" id=\"courseOthers' + rowCnt + '\" class=\"txtbox_mandatory\"  theme=\"simple\" cols=\"50\" rows=\"3"\ maxLength=\"200\" onblur=\"convertToUpper(this);\" value=\"' + otherStr + '\"/></div>';
            var str2 = '<div id=\"trainingTypeTextTd' + rowCnt + '\" align=\"center\"><select class=\"txtbox_mandatory\" theme=\"simple\"  id=\"trainingType' + rowCnt + '\" name=\"appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].trainingType\">' + s2 + '</select></div>';
            var str5 = '<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" theme=\"simple\" class=\"txtbox_mandatory_big\" cols=\"40\"  name=\"appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].reasonOfRecomndtn\" id=\"reasonOfRecomndtn' + rowCnt + '\" onblur=\"convertToUpper(this);\" onkeydown=\"textCounter(this,4000);\" onkeyup=\"textCounter(this,4000);\" value=\"' + recommendStr + '\"/></div>';
            var str8 = '<div align=\"center\"><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"btn\" id=\"deletSelfrowid\" onclick=\"deleteTrainingRow(' + rowCnt + ');\"/></div>';


            var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
            td1.innerHTML = str1;
            var td4 = document.createElement("TD");
            td4.innerHTML = str4;
            var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
            td2.innerHTML = str2;
            var td5 = document.createElement("TD");
            td5.innerHTML = str5;
            var td8 = document.createElement("TD");
            td8.innerHTML = str8;

            td1.className = "td_one1";
            td4.className = "td_one1";
            td2.className = "td_one1";
            td5.className = "td_one1";
            td8.className = "td_one1";

            row.appendChild(td1);
            row.appendChild(td4);
            row.appendChild(td2);
            row.appendChild(td5);
            row.appendChild(td8);

            tempArray[rowCnt] = row;
            index++;
            rowCnt++;
        }
    }


    //Delete all the rows 
    var table = document.getElementById("trainingTable");
    var headerRowCount = 0;
    for (var i = (existingNumOfRows); i > headerRowCount; i--) {
        table.deleteRow(i);
    }

    var tbody = document.getElementById("trainingTable").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];

    //Add the backup rows
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCnt; i++) {
        tbody.appendChild(tempArray[i]);
    }
    //set the number of rows

    document.getElementById("rowCnt").value = Number(rowCnt);
}
```

I have all the getters/setters there in the POJO class, but still the `appTrngMstrList[0]` value, I get in the `Action` class, but whatever rows I add dynamically `appTrngMstrList[1]` does not get bind to the `Action` List.

Also, I put hidden variables as a workaround, but even the `hrAppHeader.appHidenVarTrngMstrList` does not bind dynamic rows.

Comment: can u show generated html code ?

Comment: rows added/deleted using javascript will not be reflected on your action class. Are you doing form submission ?

Comment: dynamic rows don't contain input fields, it's unclear what are you trying to bind?

Comment: It has to reflect, but you have to maintain proper Indexing, but not like `appTrngMstrList[0]`, `appTrngMstrList[2]`, `appTrngMstrList[3]` etc

Comment: @shantaram_t Struts allows gaps in indexing. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20439277/573032).

Comment: Ok, I did this same using Spring but not in Struts

Comment: @shantaram_t Spring is *not* Struts.

Comment: @shantaram :thanks for the reply, how do I do the indexing,I will share with you the generated html code . I am trying to bind in appTrngMstrList the values which are dynamically added from the js.                                                
 name=\"appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].courseCode

Comment: @RomanC:Thanks for the reply .I am trying to bind in appTrngMstrList the values which are dynamically added from the js. name=\"appTrngMstrList[' + rowCnt + '].courseCode                                        and I do a form submission this way                                                                
      ** <input name="button" type="button" class="btn" id="submitButtonVerifId" value="Submit" onClick="submitVerifRecord();">**

Comment: Ok ..shantaram,C,when I view source HTML code, I am only able to see the 0th element of appTrngMstrList, but in the F12 ,chrome developer tools I am able to see the dynamically added rows, 1st element ,2nd element. Is there any way from jquery where without indexing I can set the values of java arraylist

Comment: @want2learn: yes I am doing form submission                                            *<input name="button" type="button" class="btn" id="submitButtonVerifId" value="Submit" onClick="submitVerifRecord();">*

Comment: @want2learn:you inderstood my question,so if rows added in javascript does not get bind to my action class,how do I achieve it,                                btw,thanks to all the guys for answering me,I have acrathed my head like anything, i am completely out of ideas now,please help me

Comment: @SweetAngel What is `submitVerifRecord()`?

Comment: please check what parameters are passed , in the Network tab,

Comment: @romanC : submitVerifRecord is a javascript function checking the client side validations for checks in the form

Comment: @SweetAngel Are you sure it's working properly? Because you can't submit input fields without creating a form element. If you are using jquery it allows you to serialize data manually but better to serialize the form with all input fields.

Comment: @romanC: its not working correctly...because of the input fields not reflected in jsp ,all the element which I add at js level does not get bind to the action.*better to serialize the form with all input fields*...can you please give me a code snippet on whatever your thoughts is..thanks please

Comment: No @sweetAngel, it doesn't work this way, you should show your code that you tried and expose the problem or error. Without it this question is off-topic. You should provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to give us full code required to understand the problem. Without it it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I understand,but due to discretion policy I am not able to share the entire code with you,but I will post a new thread there I will atleast post the screenshots of the java debug compiler what is happening..will that be fine

Answer (score 0):

I could not fully understand your code approach. But I am trying to answer in  general. Hope this will help

1. If you are adding/removing elements on your JSP using javascript use same name for element and different Id.

   `<input name="firstInput" id="1'+rowIndex+'" />`
2. On Your action class you will have something like

   `private String firstInput[];
        //getter and setter`

Once you submit your form, firstInput array will have value of all element with name firstInput

Comment: thanks for your help,I tried your approach,but still in the firstInput,only one value get bind to the action,that is the first value,which is present in the jsp,the values which are added from js does not get bind to the action..any other help please..

Comment: Just changing my browser solved the issue,i.s for IE9 and above versions it is not able to bind the objects but for IE8 below,the same piece of code works