# How to pass a Map<ObjectA, List<ObjectB>> to action in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, type-conversion, struts2, ognl

I have a event object, inside there is a `Map<ObjectA, List<ObjectB>>`, the `ObjectA` is the label, and the `list<ObjectB>` are table rows. With following code, I can display the tables correctly, but when I submit the form to `Action` class, the map is `null` inside the event.

**JSP CODE:**

```jsp
<s:iterator value="event.planMap" var="map" >
    <h4>Plan Type: <s:property value='key' /></h4>
    <table id="plan">
    <s:iterator value="value" status="stat" var="detail" >
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="event.planMap['%{#map.key}'][%{#stat.index}].name" value="<s:property value='name'/>"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="text" name="event.planMap['%{#map.key}'][%{#stat.index}].text" value="<s:property value='text'/>"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="contact" name="event.planMap['%{#map.key}'][%{#stat.index}].contact" value="<s:property value='contact'/>"/></td>
        </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
</s:iterator>
```

@Andrea & Roman, So I modified the code. displaying the table is correct, but I got error  and it went to Result input. If I remove the `planMap`, the action goes to success. So at least I know the error are the `planMap`.  The modified code is:

**The `Event` definition:**

```
public Event {
    private Map<Object_A, Object_B> planMap;
    public Map<Object_A, Object_B> getPlanMap {
           return this.planMap;
    }

    public void setPlanMap(Map<Object_A, Object_B> planMap) {
           this.planMap = planMap;
    }
}
```

**The `Object_B` definition:**

```
public Object_B {
    private List<Object_C> details;
    
    public List<Object_C> getDetials() {
           return this.details;
    }
    public void setDetails(List<Object_C> details) {
           this.details = details;
    }
}
```

**The JSP code is:**

```
<s:iterator value="event.planMap" status="mStat"  >
    <h4>Plan Type: <s:property value='key' /></h4>
    <table id="plan">
    <s:iterator value="value.details" status="stat">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="event.planMap['% {#mStat.index}'].details[%{#stat.index}].name" value="<s:property value='name'/>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="text" name="event.planMap['%{#mStat.index}'].details[%{#stat.index}].text" value="<s:property value='text'/>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="contact" name="event.planMap['%{#mStat.index}'].details[%{#stat.index}].contact" value="<s:property value='contact'/>"/></td>
    </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265

Comment: it didn't work after I modified to have Map<Object_A, Object_B>, in the definition of Object_B, having List<Object_C> details. the JSP is, <s:iterator value="event.planMap" stat="mStat">    
    <table id="plan">
    <s:iterator value="value" status="stat">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name" name="event.planMap['%{#mStat.index}'].details[%{#stat.index}].name" value="<s:property value='name'/>"/></td>
                 </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
</s:iterator>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work after the following change.

```
<s:iterator value="event.planMap" status="mStat"  >
<h4>Plan Type: <s:property value='key' /></h4>
<table id="plan">
<s:iterator value="value.details" status="stat">
<tr>
    <td><s:textfield id="name" name="event.planMap['%{key}'].details[%{#stat.index}].name" /></td>
    <td><s:textfield  id="text" name="event.planMap['%{key}'].details[%{#stat.index}].text" /></td>
    <td><s:textfield id="contact" name="event.planMap['%{key}].details[%{#stat.index}].contact" /></td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 2):

The Struts can access indexed properties of the action bean, such as `List`, `Map`, etc., but it's required that the element class should be a Java Bean like `Map<ObjectA, ObjectC>`, where `ObjectC` wraps `List<ObjectB>`.

Then use Struts [type conversion](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/type-conversion.html) to populate the indexed property like in this answer [How to get updated list values from JSP in my action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19155411/573032).

> ### Indexing a collection by a property of that collection
>
> It is also possible to obtain a unique element of a collection by
> passing the value of a given property of that element. By default, the
> property of the element of the collection is determined in
> `Class-conversion.properties` using `KeyProperty_xxx=yyy`, where `xxx`
> is the property of the bean Class that returns the collection and
> `yyy` is the property of the collection element that we want to index
> on.
>
> For an example, see the following two classes:
>
> MyAction.java
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @return a Collection of Foo objects
>  */
> public Collection getFooCollection()
> {
>     return foo;
> }
> ```
>
> Foo.java
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @return a unique identifier
>  */
> public Long getId()
> {
>     return id;
> }
> ```

---