# Error setting expression 'spa.amount' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@10dd65e' )

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, model-driven

I am trying following code to get data in `spa` object fields. Thus, I am using the following code but it is showing `null` values and giving the following error

```
Error setting expression 'spa.amount' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@10dd65e'
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "amount", [Ljava.lang.String;@10dd65e)
```

**JSP code:**

```jsp
<s:form action="UpdatedPaid" method="post">  
        <s:if test="paidList.size >  0"> 
            <s:iterator value="paidList" var="pdlst">
                <div class="box">
                    <span class="label">Amount</span>
                    <span class="ib"> 
                        <s:hidden name="spa.id" id="paidId">
                            <s:param name="value">
                                <s:property value="paidId"/>
                            </s:param>
                        </s:hidden>
                        <s:textfield name="spa.amount" id="amount">
                            <s:param name="value">
                                <s:property value="amount"/>
                            </s:param>
                        </s:textfield>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <span class="label">Payment Date</span>
                    <span class="ib"> <s:textfield name="spa.paymentDate" id="paymentDate">
                            <s:param name="value">
                                <s:property value="paymentDate"/>
                            </s:param>
                        </s:textfield>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <span class="label">Payment Mode</span>
                    <span class="ib">
                        <s:textfield name="spa.paymentMode" id="payment_mode" readonly="true">
                            <s:param name="value">
                                <s:property value="payment_mode"/>
                            </s:param>
                        </s:textfield>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:if>
    </s:form>
```

**My Action class:**

```
package iland.payment;

import static com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action.SUCCESS;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import iland.hbm.SupplierPaidDetails;

public class hbmCashAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<SupplierPaidDetails> {

    SupplierPaidDetails spa = new SupplierPaidDetails();

    public SupplierPaidDetails getSpa() {
        return spa;
    }

    public void setSpa(SupplierPaidDetails spa) {
        this.spa = spa;
    }

    public String update() {
        System.out.println("--------");
        System.out.println(spa.getId() + " " + spa.getPaymentMode() + " " + spa.getAmount());
        System.out.println("--------");
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public SupplierPaidDetails getModel() {
        return spa;
    }

}
```

**`SupplierPaidDetails` class:**

```
public class SupplierPaidDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Long id;
     private SupplierPaymentDetails supplierPaymentDetails;
     private Float amount;
     private String paymentMode;
     private Date paymentDate;
     private Date addDate;
     private String status;
     private Set supplierPaidOnlines = new HashSet(0);
     private Set supplierPaidCashes = new HashSet(0);
     private Set supplierPaidChecks = new HashSet(0);

    public SupplierPaidDetails() {
    }

    
    public SupplierPaidDetails(SupplierPaymentDetails supplierPaymentDetails, Date addDate) {
        this.supplierPaymentDetails = supplierPaymentDetails;
        this.addDate = addDate;
    }
    public SupplierPaidDetails(SupplierPaymentDetails supplierPaymentDetails, Float amount, String paymentMode, Date paymentDate, Date addDate, String status, Set supplierPaidOnlines, Set supplierPaidCashes, Set supplierPaidChecks) {
       this.supplierPaymentDetails = supplierPaymentDetails;
       this.amount = amount;
       this.paymentMode = paymentMode;
       this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
       this.addDate = addDate;
       this.status = status;
       this.supplierPaidOnlines = supplierPaidOnlines;
       this.supplierPaidCashes = supplierPaidCashes;
       this.supplierPaidChecks = supplierPaidChecks;
    }
   
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public SupplierPaymentDetails getSupplierPaymentDetails() {
        return this.supplierPaymentDetails;
    }
    
    public void setSupplierPaymentDetails(SupplierPaymentDetails supplierPaymentDetails) {
        this.supplierPaymentDetails = supplierPaymentDetails;
    }
    public Float getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }
    
    public void setAmount(Float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getPaymentMode() {
        return this.paymentMode;
    }
    
    public void setPaymentMode(String paymentMode) {
        this.paymentMode = paymentMode;
    }
    public Date getPaymentDate() {
        return this.paymentDate;
    }
    
    public void setPaymentDate(Date paymentDate) {
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
    }
    public Date getAddDate() {
        return this.addDate;
    }
    
    public void setAddDate(Date addDate) {
        this.addDate = addDate;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Set getSupplierPaidOnlines() {
        return this.supplierPaidOnlines;
    }
    
    public void setSupplierPaidOnlines(Set supplierPaidOnlines) {
        this.supplierPaidOnlines = supplierPaidOnlines;
    }
    public Set getSupplierPaidCashes() {
        return this.supplierPaidCashes;
    }
    
    public void setSupplierPaidCashes(Set supplierPaidCashes) {
        this.supplierPaidCashes = supplierPaidCashes;
    }
    public Set getSupplierPaidChecks() {
        return this.supplierPaidChecks;
    }
    
    public void setSupplierPaidChecks(Set supplierPaidChecks) {
        this.supplierPaidChecks = supplierPaidChecks;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I want to set all fields of `SupplierPaidDetails` class including setting of (`supplierPaidOnlines`,`supplierPaidCashes`,`supplierPaidChecks` these can contains many instances) and `supplierPaymentDetails` from JSP.

How to resolve above errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error

```
Error setting expression 'spa.amount' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@10dd65e'
```

seems that OGNL is trying to set a value of type `String[]` to `amount` property of `spa` bean.

Reading further

```
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "amount", [Ljava.lang.String;@10dd65e)
```

looks like `spa` reference is `null`, so OGNL is unable to set a value to a `null` because it will throw a null pointer exception.

To resolve the issue you should initialize the reference of `spa`.

Next the problem arises because you use a model driven. The model driven interceptor pushes a model on top of the value stack, which is an OGNL root. And you have initialized the instance of `spa`. Seems that OGNL even if searches from the top of the value stack down the stack can't find the instance of `spa`. So, to access action properties directly you can use technique described in this answer [Passing parameters to action through ModelDriven in Struts 2.3.16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21282401/573032).

The method expected by OGNL on reference of `spa` is

```
public void setAmount(String[] amounts) {
   this.amounts = amounts;
}
```

You don't have such method and you probably not expected to receive an array of strings. But the problem is that you are doing it. Because parameters with the same name are packaged into `String[]`. To have different names corresponding to each iterated object you should use indexed property names. You can find an example if indexed properties in this answer [Repopulate an ArrayList from JSP with Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657572/573032).

Your properties are available directly from the model because your action is model driven and it should have a `List<SupplierPaymentDetails> paidList` that is iterated. You can use this property to populate the submitted values or use another with the same type.

[ModelDriven example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-modeldriven-example/) you can learn, but it doesn't use indexed properties. To use it properly you can use this answer [`How to pass a Map<ObjectA, List<ObjectB>> to action in Struts 2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23251686/573032).

Comment: I would like set only one value for amount

Comment: i want to set value of all fields of `SupplierPaidDetails`. how to initialize all fields value including set(`supplierPaidOnlines`,`supplierPaidCashes`,`supplierPaidChecks`) from jsp

Comment: I resolved above error instead of using `spa.id` or `obj.fieldName` I used only fieldName like Id. as given here example for model driven http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-modeldriven-example/

Comment: The error was about `spa.amount`, not `spa.id` or `obj.fieldName`.

Comment: but I used only `amount` instead of spa.amount then error resolved

Comment: ok, if the issue was resolved then you could accept this answer.

Comment: Your answer not exactly matching with my requirement cound you please update as given in above link

Comment: @xrcwrn I updated the answer with detailed explanations.