# My data type property can not be set by ModelDriven

Tags: java, struts2

This is my action class:

```
    public class AdminCategorySecondAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<CategorySecond> {
    private CategorySecond categorySecond = new CategorySecond();

    @Override
    public CategorySecond getModel() {
    return categorySecond;
    }

    /*
    * add categorySecond
    */
    public String add() {
    System.out.println("property category:"+categorySecond.getCategory());
    categorySecondService.add(categorySecond);
    return "add";
    }
}
```

This is my entity class *Cagorysecond*:

```
    public class CategorySecond {
    private int csid;
    private String csname;
    private Category category ;
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>();

    public int getCsid() {
        return csid;
    }
    public void setCsid(int csid) {
        this.csid = csid;
    }
    public String getCsname() {
        return csname;
    }
    public void setCsname(String csname) {
        this.csname = csname;
    }
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

This is another entity *Category*:

```
    public class Category {
    private int cid;
    private String cname;
    private Set<CategorySecond> categoryseconds = new HashSet<CategorySecond>();

    public int getCid() {
        return cid;
    }
    public void setCid(int cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }
    public String getCname() {
        return cname;
    }
    public void setCname(String cname) {
        this.cname = cname;
    }
    public Set<CategorySecond> getCategoryseconds() {
        return categoryseconds;
    }
    public void setCategoryseconds(Set<CategorySecond> categoryseconds) {
        this.categoryseconds = categoryseconds;
    }
}
```

This is the form in JSP:

```
    <form id="userAction_save_do" name="Form1" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/adminCategorySecond_add.action" method="post">
    <select name="category.cid">
        <s:iterator var="c" value="cList">
            <option value="<s:property value="#c.cid"/>"><s:property value="#c.cname"/></option>
        </s:iterator>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="userAction_save_do_submit" value="确定" class="button_ok">
        &#30830;&#23450;
    </button>
    </form>
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

<package name="usermodel" extends="struts-default">
    <global-results>
        <result name="msg">/WEB-INF/jsp/msg.jsp</result>
    </global-results>
    <action name="index" class="indexAction" method="execute">
        <result name="index">/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="unlogin">/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="user_*" class="userAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="registPage">/WEB-INF/jsp/regist.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/regist.jsp</result>
        <result name="loginPage">/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="activate">/WEB-INF/jsp/activated.jsp</result>
        <result name="loginSuccess" type="redirectAction">index</result>
        <result name="loginFail">/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="quit" type="redirectAction">user_loginPage</result>
    </action>
    <action name="checkCode" class="checkImaAction" method="execute"></action>
    <action name="product_*" class="productAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="productFindByPid">/WEB-INF/jsp/product.jsp</result>
        <result name="productsFindByCsid">/WEB-INF/jsp/productList.jsp</result>
        <result name="productsFindByCid">/WEB-INF/jsp/productList.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="cart_*" class="cartAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="add">/WEB-INF/jsp/cart.jsp</result>
        <result name="clear">/WEB-INF/jsp/cart.jsp</result>
        <result name="remove">/WEB-INF/jsp/cart.jsp</result>
        <result name="show">/WEB-INF/jsp/cart.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="order_*" class="orderAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="generate">/WEB-INF/jsp/order.jsp</result>
        <result name="cartIsNull" type="redirectAction">cart_show</result>
        <result name="findByUid">/WEB-INF/jsp/orderList.jsp</result>
        <result name="findByOid">/WEB-INF/jsp/order.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="adminUser_*" class="adminUserAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="loginSuccess">admin/home.jsp</result>
        <result name="loginFail">admin/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="adminCategory_*" class="adminCategoryAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="findAll">admin/category/list.jsp</result>
        <result name="add" type="redirectAction">adminCategory_findAll</result>
        <result name="delete" type="redirectAction">adminCategory_findAll</result>
        <result name="update" type="redirectAction">adminCategory_findAll</result>
        <result name="edit">admin/category/edit.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="adminCategorySecond_*" class="adminCategorySecondAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="findAll">admin/categorysecond/list.jsp</result>
        <result name="addPage">admin/categorysecond/add.jsp</result>
        <result name="editPage">admin/categorysecond/edit.jsp</result>
        <result name="add" type="redirectAction">adminCategorySecond_findAll</result>
        <result name="update" type="redirectAction">adminCategorySecond_findAll</result>
        <result name="delete" type="redirectAction">adminCategorySecond_findAll</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

This is the error message and console output:

```
08:16:02,213 ERROR InstantiatingNullHandler:38 - Could not create and/or set value back on to object
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.inspectClass(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:112)
    at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowire(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:344)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.createObject(InstantiatingNullHandler.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.InstantiatingNullHandler.nullPropertyValue(InstantiatingNullHandler.java:137)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlNullHandlerWrapper.nullPropertyValue(OgnlNullHandlerWrapper.java:21)
    at ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:118)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTChain.setValueBody(ASTChain.java:222)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
    at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:183)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:170)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:318)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:231)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
08:16:02,215  WARN OgnlValueStack:64 - Error setting expression 'category.cid' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@4c2858f8'
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "cid", [Ljava.lang.String;@4c2858f8)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2326)
    at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
    at ognl.ASTChain.setValueBody(ASTChain.java:227)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
    at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:183)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:170)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setParameter(OgnlValueStack.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:318)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:231)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
property category:null
```

**this is my question:** 
*How to auto set my data type property category by ModelDriven when I submit the form.
*

Comment: You declared classes as `Serializable` but they don't implement this interface.

Comment: @RomanC yeah, but that's not the main point.

Comment: What is the main point?

Comment: @RomanC I mean that lack of serialized id won't cause this problem.although I give an id to my entity ,the problem still exists.

Comment: I was asked what is the problem? Also include necessary information: struts version, `struts.xml`, `web.xml`, `web-inf/lib` contents, full stacktrace, etc.

Comment: @RomanC do you have a Skype account?

Comment: Why do you need my Skype account?

Comment: @RomanC to explain the problem easily,you know,any information you want know I could provide immediately

Comment: You can provide it here via editing the question, you don't need my Skype account for it.

Comment: @RomanC ok ,it looks like that I didn't express my problems clearly.i will try my best to say it again.please notice that entity CategorySecond has a reference object  property called category.the category has a primary type property called cid.also notice the form.in the form i have a select tag that  name is "category.cid" .i submit it's value to my action but I failed.because I can't get it using "categorySecond.getCategory().getCid()".this is the problem.

Comment: I understand your problem well but actual calls by OGNL `getCategory().setCid()` if you are using `category.cid` name. But you didn't post information I have asked you, so I can't identify your error with my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23427006/573032), and it seems impossible to post a correct answer.

Comment: @RomanC I have added some information.hope help

Comment: @RomanC you are right. "calls by OGNL getCategory().setCid() if you are using category.cid name."but  actually when method getCategory() called,who create the instance of Category? now the "category.getCategory()" is null from the console

Comment: I see from the logs that you use spring object factory that fails to return an instance of `Category` due `IllegalArgumentException at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader`. Do you have `asm-xxx.jar` libraries in `web-inf/lib`?

Comment: @RomanC yes i have that jar file.asm-3.3.jar

Comment: What would be if you remove `CategorySecond` dependency from `Category`?

Comment: @RomanC could you tell me why do you wanna do this?

Comment: @RomanC who create the instance of Category?spring?it failed to generate an instance of Category,so i it can not set the cid to category.why does it failed?could you figure out that for me ?

Comment: No, I couldn't figure it out, you didn't answer my questions and I couldn't reproduce it.